# Why was my comment deleted, but not the replies to it?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted

I posted a highly upvoted comment which was not asking for clarification on the question, so I understand why it was deleted. But why weren't the replies to my comment deleted also?

This is not the first time I have seen this happen. It is confusing when there are replies to a comment that doesn't exist.

Question is [Should I reveal productivity tricks to peers, or keep them to myself in order to be more productive than the others?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/145663/26998)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a moderator takes a look at comment flags and removed any subsequent comments that have been orphaned by their removal.

However, some get missed.  If you see this happen, flag the orphaned comments as "no longer needed" so that they can be picked up and removed as appropriate.